# Android Studio 4.0 error; Cause: invalid type code: 3A

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I just upgraded to AS version 4.0 from 3.6 and now one of my projects fails during Gradle sync. The project would build without a problem before the upgrade. I need help figuring out the problem.

The stack trace from `idea.log` is:

```
2020-06-02 11:08:35,533 [  40337]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run phased build action using Gradle installation '/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/5.5.1/libexec'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 3A
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.throwFailure(ProviderConnection.java:208)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:196)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runPhasedAction(ProviderConnection.java:171)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:233)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:76)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 3A
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1656)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2030)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2266)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:74)
    ... 19 more
2020-06-02 11:08:35,559 [  40363]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [/Users/tedhopp/AndroidStudioProjects/TanachApps] resolution task executed in 23203 ms. 
2020-06-02 11:08:35,560 [  40364]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Cause: invalid type code: 3A

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (23 s 272 ms) 
2020-06-02 11:08:35,572 [  40376]   INFO - roid.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace - Updating model took 0.003s 
2020-06-02 11:08:35,889 [  40693]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 2 ms 
2020-06-02 11:13:00,653 [ 305457]   WARN - dea.sdk.SystemInfoStatsMonitor - CpuInfoFlags.fromExitCode(): unknown flag values '0x80'
```

This happens whether I'm using version 4.0.0 or version 3.6.3 of the Android Gradle plugin. I've also tried setting various versions of Gradle (5.5.1, 5.6.4, and 6.1.1). I've tried cleaning the project and also clearing the cache and restarting AS. Nothing changes the behavior.

Other projects sync and compile without a problem since the upgrade to AS 4.0. I should mention that the option "Only sync the active variant" is disabled (a solution suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54235107/535871) to a similar question).

Here's the gradle-wrapper.properties file for both the problem project and another project that works:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

and here is the `buildscript` section of the project-level `build.gradle` file for both projects:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    }
}
```

In looking at the stack trace, I'm puzzled as to why it is using the Gradle installation at `/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/5.5.1/libexec`. There's no reason AS should be using that version. (There's certainly nothing in my environment variables that points to that installation.)

I have no idea what to try next, or where to look for the source of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache

Comment: @DavidEnoma - Yes. I believe I mentioned that in the question.

Comment: I remember these corruptions were happening a lot after upgrading from AS 2.0 to 3.0. They got fixed after some time, IIRC, not sure I ever did anything about it except invalidating caches. My suggestions for now would be: delete gradle caches in `~/.gradle/caches` (if you don't mind all dependencies being redownloaded), maybe even the whole `.gradle` folder, and open an issue on the AS issue tracker. As for the gradle installation folder have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646252). Looks like that's where Homebrew installs gradle?

Comment: Ran into this again earlier today; Invalidating caches, cleaning, etc didn't work, however running `./gradlew --stop` and `./gradlew assembleDebug --no-build-cache` seemed to get things working again for me. Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I managed to fix this was to create an entirely new AS project and bring in my source code from version control.

My theory is that my project files included some cruft from previous versions of Android Studio that caused the problem. If I had more motivation, perhaps I could have tracked down exactly what was causing the error, but once I had the new project up and running, I was done.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to latest version

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I had already tried using Gradle 6.1.1.

Comment: Try changing the directory of the project and reopen. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by downloading gradle version 6.1.1 and after connecting with android studio.

Then use invalidate caches/restart

File>Invalidate Caches/ Restart...

After this my problem was solved

so try this step...

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I had already tried using Gradle 6.1.1.