# Cause: invalid type code: 69 Android studio while building

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting above mentioned error while building my android project in android studio version 4.0 and gradle version 4.0.0.

Comment: I suggest you try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54235107/8738452).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 3.3.0 update, ERROR: Cause: invalid type code: 68](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214605/android-3-3-0-update-error-cause-invalid-type-code-68)

Comment: not helped both suggesions

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue, Solved by set `ndk.dir` path in `local.properties`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error resolved on setting the correct ndk version in `build.gradle` file.

Example configuration:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  ndkVersion "18.1.5063045"
  defaultConfig {
  ........
```

You can click on the first line in Build Output to get full information about the error:
[image]

Comment: but i'm not using NDK here...